# How can I get the total bundle size when building with vite?

Tags: vite

I'm refactoring my React app built with Vite to try to remove some dependencies.  When I execute `npm run build`, I get a list of all the various bundles output by Vite.  Is there an easy way to get vite to print the total bundle size of all bundles?

I want to check the total bundle size to make sure that the app is actually getting smaller instead of code just being moved around between different bundles.

Comment: `du -hs ./build` (or whatever your build dir is)? Or are you looking for something programatic? Vite uses Rollup, and [some Rollup plugins Just Work](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin.html#rollup-plugin-compatibility) if they're under `build` in your Vite config, probably including rollup-plugin-filesize, rollup-plugin-bundle-size, or rollup-plugin-sizes.